# fullscreen background html5 doesn't work well with google chrome browser

Tags: css, html

I have made a website with fullscreen background. It works fine on Safari and IE but not on Google Chrome, the video is not centered and is completely cut on the top right of the screen.

CSS and HTML:

```css
#Video-Background {
    min-height: 100%;
    min-width: 100%;
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: -100;
    transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
}
```

```html
<video id="video-background" autoplay="autoplay" loop>
    <source src="Reel 2015-simovie.webmhd.webm" type="video/webm">
    <source src="Reel 2015-simovie.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    <source src="Reel 2015-simovie.oggtheora.ogv" type="video/ogg">
</video>
```

Please take a look of my so you ll see how it looks like on [simovie-p.com](http://www.simovie-p.com).

Comment: I noticed that the lack of matching case sensitivity for the `id` selector in CSS caused the styling not to apply. `id`s are case-sensitive.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your code for centering the video is incorrect. You have both `left` and `top` set to `0`. The transform centering trick you are attempting to use, requires both `left` and `top` being `50%`, with the transform being `-50%`.

```
#Video-Background {
    min-height: 100%;
    min-width: 100%;
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    position: fixed;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    z-index: -100;
    -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
        -ms-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
            transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
}
```

This may appear to be working in IE and Safari, if you are not including the `-webkit-` (Safari) and `-ms-` (IE9) vendor prefixes for `transform`, or IE8 and older which do not support transforms, or the video element for that matter.

(You also have different letter casing in your ID selector in your example, but this is not the case on your website, so I'm guessing this is not your issue.)

Comment: when I write 50% at top and left, my video is completely cut and out of the background

Comment: @SimonParaire I'm guessing this is happening in Safari, but working in Firefox/Chrome? I've updated the code above to include the necessary vendor prefixes.

Comment: I added -webkit- and -ms- and now the video is not centered anywhere,not even on safari, google chrome.. it moved and is cut at the top left of the screen

Comment: @SimonParaire Did you use both the vendor prefixes and left/top 50%? It should work if you use both.

Comment: @AlexanderOMara here is the code i've wrote `#video-background {
min-height: 100%;
min-width: 100%;
width: auto;
height: auto;
position: fixed;
top: 50%;
left: 50%;
z-index: -100;
   -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%) ;
   -ms-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
            transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);`

Comment: @SimonParaire When I apply that CSS to the `#bgvid` element on your example site via Firefox developer tools, it works.

Comment: @AlexanderOMara when i load my website on safari or google chrome the video is still out of the frame, what i can only see is the bottom left corner

Comment: @SimonParaire The styles above also work when I use the `#bgvid` selector in Chrome, when added via Chrome developer tools. Are you mixing up the ID's, or getting a caches CSS file?

Answer (score 0):

try styling with

```
#video-background {
    min-height: 100%;
    min-width: 100%;
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: -100;
    transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
}
```